# lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression unresolved bug

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have been trying for many days to resolve this lxml-xpath error but I have not been able to. I already to install the respective libraries with pip install and i have selected the respective python selector. I do not understand why the expression "parsed.xpath" is a wrong expression. I would like to know if somedody can to help me with this bug.

**Code:**

```
import requests
import lxml.html as html

HOME_URL = 'https://www.larepublica.co/' #URL de la página home

XPATH_LINK_TO_ARTICLE = "$x('//div[@class='newsV_Title_Img' or @class='V_Title']/text-fill/a/@href').map(x => x.value)"
XPATH_TITLE = "$x('//full-text/span/text()').map(x => x.wholeText)"
XPATH_SUMMARY = "$x('//div[@class='lead']/p/text()').map(x => x.wholeText)"
XPATH_BODY = "$x('//div[@class='html-content']/p[not(@class)]/text()').map(x => x.wholeText)"

#Función para extraer los links de las noticias
def parse_home():
    #Envolver el código dentro de un bloque try except
    try:
        response = requests.get(HOME_URL)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            home = response.content.decode('utf-8')
            parsed = html.fromstring(home) 
            links_to_notices = parsed.xpath(XPATH_LINK_TO_ARTICLE) 
            print(links_to_notices)
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Error: {response.status_code}') 
    except ValueError as ve: 
        print(ve)

def run():
    parse_home()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

**Console output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Andres\PLATZI\Curso_Fundamentos_WebScrapping\LaRepublica_Scrapper\scraper.py", line 30, in <module>
    run()
  File "D:\Andres\PLATZI\Curso_Fundamentos_WebScrapping\LaRepublica_Scrapper\scraper.py", line 27, in run
    parse_home()
  File "D:\Andres\PLATZI\Curso_Fundamentos_WebScrapping\LaRepublica_Scrapper\scraper.py", line 19, in parse_home
    links_to_notices = parsed.xpath(XPATH_LINK_TO_ARTICLE) #Obtener lista de links con comandos xtpath del documento contenido en parsed
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1599, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 305, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.__call__
  File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 225, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result
lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to use JavaScript (console) features like `$x` or `map(x => x.value)` in your XPath expressions, which you are, however, trying to evaluate with Python:

```
$x('//div[@class='newsV_Title_Img' or @class='V_Title']/text-fill/a/@href').map(x => x.value)
```

So the XPath expression is only

```
//div[@class='newsV_Title_Img' or @class='V_Title']/text-fill/a/@href
```

the rest is JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you very much, it already worked! that was the bug!!